# Change the directory to "C:\Users\<username>" with Python OS

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system

I want to write a program that goes to the Desktop folder, and do commands like make a folder. I have this:

```
import os


def run_command(command):
    os.system(f'cmd /c "{command}"')


"""
This command is running in the folder of this Python file, thus I can only access folders from this directory.
But I want it to go to the Desktop folder and make a new directory there. 
"""
run_command("cd Desktop")  # It makes an error "The system cannot find the path specified."
run_command("md Folder")
r"""I want the directory to be C:\Users\<username>"""
```

As you can see in the comments, it does everything in the directory you ran this Python file. But I want the directory to be "C:\Users<username>". This is what you get if your open cmd prompt manually. How do I make its directory be "C:\Users<username>"? Or if there is a better way, how do I do it?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.chdir` to change the directory that Python is "running in".

```
os.chdir('C:\Users\someuser')
```

Answer (score 2):

Like James said, `os.chdir` should work. But you should keep in mind that the character `\` is an escape character, and in order to use it, the string must be prefixed with a r: `r"C:\Users\user"` or it must be escaped: `"C:\\Users\\user"`.

Also a easy way to get the current user is by using the built-in `getpass` module.

```py
import getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
```

Answer (score 1):

This code makes use of environment variables to get the correct Desktop directory and to invoke the correct command processor.

It also uses `os.path.join` to create the directory path. Since `Desktop` is hardcoded, a REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) could probably also be hardcoded. But, making a practice of using `os.path.join` will make code portable to all systems on which Python runs.

```
import os

def run_command(command):
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop'))
    os.system(os.environ['ComSpec'] + ' /c "cd"')
```